# Woocommerce how to edit the email template for low stock notification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

How can I edit the email template of `low stock` notification, `sender` email and the `subject` of that email?

Answer (score 0):

There's only filters (and a database setting) for those, the stock emails don't have the full templates/settings like the other emails.

- Recipient: `woocommerce_email_recipient_low_stock` filter or the `woocommerce_stock_email_recipient` option in the database.
- Subject: `woocommerce_email_subject_low_stock` filter.
- Email content: `woocommerce_email_content_low_stock` filter.

For the "from" address, I think it uses the setting for the site.